# Method incorrectly returning Image object c#.Net

Tags: .net, image, methods

Im having an issue where I got a method that takes an Image object, processes it to 1 colour channel (the other 2 are solid black) then returns a new image from the process.

Now the issue I have is that when I create the new image in the method and I look at the object during debugging the image object appears perfectly fine. BUT when I return it to an empty Image object the properties inside that Image object all show "System.ArgumentException"

here is the code of that Method:

```
    public Image GetRedImage(Image sourceImage)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage))
        using (Bitmap redBmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pxl = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color redPxl = Color.FromArgb((int)pxl.R, 1, 1);

                    redBmp.SetPixel(x, y, redPxl);
                }
            }
            Image tout = (Image)redBmp;

            return tout;
        }

    }
```

anyone got any ideas on what the hell is going on?

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using the `using` blocks you are disposing the images as soon as you leave the using scope.

try to replace these two lines from the top:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage))
using (Bitmap redBmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height))
```

with:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage);
Bitmap redBmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);
```

now it should work, depending on your program logic you will have to dispose those images manually afterwards.

you could probably dispose `bmp` also with the using but surely not the `redBmp` object as you are basically returning it, so either you clone it and return a clone, or you do not dispose it, or you return a disposed unusable object like what is happening right now.

Comment: *grins*

thankyou all for you help (especially to Davide)

it returns correctly now

many many thanks

Comment: then vote answers and accept the one you consider the best ;-)

Answer (score 3):

redBmp is getting disposed by your using block, and tout is redBmp cast to the Image type. drop the using block for redBmp.

Menno

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped `redBmp` in a `using` statement so that it's `Dispose` method is called when the method exits.  If you're going to use it outside the method (you've cast it as an `Image` and are returning it), you shouldn't be disposing of it.

```
public Image GetRedImage(Image sourceImage)
{
    Bitmap redBmp = null;
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage))
    {
        redBmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                Color pxl = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color redPxl = Color.FromArgb((int)pxl.R, 1, 1);

                redBmp.SetPixel(x, y, redPxl);
            }
        }
    }

    return redBmp as Image;
}
```